# TYPO3 tt_content: Add class to nav-wrap for specific menu element

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I'm building a custom menu type and need to change the "outerOuterWrap" of this menu.

This is what i got:

```
tt_content.menu.20.102 < tt_content.menu.20.default
tt_content.menu.20.102 {
    special = list
    stdWrap {
        outerWrap = <ul class="csc-menu csc-menu-102">|</ul>
    }

    1 = TMENU
    1.NO {
        (...)
    }
}
```

And it will be rendered to:

```
<nav class="csc-default" id="c1416">
  <ul class="csc-menu csc-menu-102">
    (...)
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How do I add a class to the nav tag without section_frame or layout? So that I get:

```
<nav class="csc-default custom-class" id="c1416">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is in Line 454 of css_styled_content/static/setup.txt:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.20.20.10.value = csc-default
```

so you would need to set this value from inside your menu definition, just for your menu. Of which I'm not sure if it's possible.